# How to pass multiple suiteXML files from command line

Tags: maven, testng, pom.xml

I am required to run multiple XML suite files from command line.

My POM.xml -

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
    <configuration>
        <suiteXmlFiles>
                <suiteXmlFile>src/test/resources/xml_Suites/${tests}.xml</suiteXmlFile>
        </suiteXmlFiles>
        <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Trying this from command line -

```
mvn clean -Dtests={abcd,xyz} test
```

Only xyz.xml is being triggered while abcd.xml is not being triggered.

Basically only the last xml file mentioned in the braces is being triggered.

Is there anything wrong in the above syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to specify using enitre path
Change -Dtests=src/test/resources/xml_Suites/abcd.xml,src/test/resources/xml_Suites/xyz.xml

Comment: But the path is already available in <suiteXmlFile> right -     <suiteXmlFile>src/test/resources/xml_Suites/${tests}.xml</suiteXmlFile>

Comment: Just keep ${tests} in the <suiteXmlFile> tag and remove the rest.  With multiple files it doesn't expand to <suiteXmlFile>src/test/resources/xml_Suites/abc.xml</suiteXmlFile><suiteXmlFile>src/test/resources/xml_Suites/xyz.xml</suiteXmlFile>  With single file, it will work.

Comment: Thanks @niharika. Works after the change. I basically removed the path from XML & passed the complete path from CLI.

Answer (score 0):

Below Sample worked for me :

```
mvn test -Dsurefire.suiteXmlFiles=/Users/mdafsarali/repository/path/IOS.xml,/Users/mdafsarali/repository/path/IOS2.xml,/Users/mdafsarali/repository/path/IOS3.xml
```