# How to combine and run testng xml files from different projects using maven?

Tags: java, xml, maven, selenium, testng

I have three projects and testng xml files in each of them.

#### Project A

```
testA.xml
```

#### Project B

```
testB.xml
```

#### Project C

```
testC.xml
```

For a single project, I am running the tests using this command:

```
mvn clean install -Dsurefire.suiteXmlFiles=testA.xml
```

I want to combine and run the tests from all projects. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15751874/how-to-pass-multiple-suitexml-files-from-command-line

Answer (score 0):

Create a variable in pom.xml for suiteXMlFile like below :

```
<plugin>
<artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.5</version>
<configuration>
    <suiteXmlFiles>
            <suiteXmlFile>${sources}</suiteXmlFile>
    </suiteXmlFiles>
    <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
</configuration>
```

Then from command line :

```
mvn clean install -Dsources=testA.xml,testB.xml,testC.xml
```

If you want to execute a single suite, use :

```
mvn clean install -Dsources=testA.xml
```

Note : the path to suite xmls should be absolute.